# Getting Mobile number service provider

Tags: mobile

I am planning to make a shopping cart in my website, the website will keep the registered members updated about the products in the website by sending sms messages to their mobile phone.  For sending sms i want to find the service providers for their mobile numbers.

Is there any database available which maps the service providers and the mobile numbers, for example, numbers which starts with 959 is AirTel etc.  I did google and i did not get any kind of useful links.

Or i am asking at the wrong place!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You wont be able to do this, phones on the same network can start with different numbers, also if you change networks you can keep your number so there can be no pattern.

You will have to ask users to input their network when registering their numbers, but even then if a user changes network then your records will be incorrect.

There are some websites claiming to be able to check for you, although I don't know how reliable they are:

If you are dealing only with uk numbers: http://www.aql.com/sms/network-lookup/developers/
(they charge you per query)

alternativly: http://www.mobilephonechecker.co.uk/network-checker/
(I dont know if this is only uk)